# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. MVC4 Razor, already elminated any parameters in constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

UPDATE: I added Bind Exclude for the select list items.

Now, i'm getting there is no ViewDataItem of type IEnumerable that has they key blah blah...

If I can't use the viewModel for select lists, then what is the point?

Getting this error on POST action.  I know this has been asked before, but I 've followed instructions to no avail.  Any thoughts about what could be wrong?  Not sure if I should include the view or not...

Here is the model:

public class Outreach
    {

```
    [DisplayName("Number of Mailings")]
    [Range(1, 100000,ErrorMessage="Please a positive number for Number of Mailings")]
    public int mailings { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Number of Calls")]
    public int pcalls { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Number of Emails")]
    public int emails { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Number of Walkins")]
    public int walkins { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Number of Faxes")]
    public int faxes { get; set; }
    public int osid { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }

    public Outreach()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
public class OutreachViewModel
  {
    [DisplayName("Outreach Specialist")]
    public SelectList OutreachSpecialist{ get; set; }
    public SelectList Year { get; set; }
    public SelectList Month { get; set; }

    public Outreach Out {get; set;}   
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<tblOutreachSpecialist> spec = repo.getAllSpecialists();
            List<pYear> years=repo.getAllYears();
            List<pMonth> months=repo.getAllMonths();

            OutreachViewModel vw = new OutreachViewModel();

            vw.Year = new SelectList(years, "id", "pYear1");
            vw.Month = new SelectList(months, "id", "pMonth1");
            vw.OutreachSpecialist = new SelectList(spec, "OSID", "LastName");

            return View(vw);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(OutreachViewModel vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repo.Add(vm.Out);
                repo.Save();

            }
            return View(vm);
        }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error at?

Comment: On the Get or the Post?

Comment: Getting it on the post.

Comment: You could try `[Bind(Exclude="OutreachSpecialist,Year,Month")]` on the ViewModel class.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a different view model for the post method.

```
            public class OutreachViewModelForCreate
            {
                public Outreach Out { get; set; }
            }
```

Then, have your post action take that simpler view model. If the model state isn't valid and you need to re-show the view to get new user input, you can call a method to convert the create view model into an instance of the display view model:

```
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(OutreachViewModelForCreate result)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //write to repo
                }
                var displayVm = getCreateDisplayViewModel();

                displayVm.Out = result.Out;

                return View(displayVm);
            }
```

You could also use a custom model binder, but I personally prefer this pattern.

Update: I see you went with bind exclude. I'll leave this here just in case.